# EF4 does not commit Updates

Tags: entity-framework-4

Sorry to ask such a general question: what can cause EF to insert records but not update ?

I face a strange situation where i change an entity and when i call SaveChanges(), the changes are not committed in the DB.
thanks
Jon

Comment: Could you post your model and the code you use for inserting and updating?

Comment: I do not get any error. Just that no SQL Update command is issued.

Comment: @Yakimych: the code is so big that i don't know how to isolate

Comment: The answer to the question "what can cause EF to insert records, but not update" would be "a bug in the code". If you want us to help you find it, please try to provide a useful sample. Otherwise, it's just guessing. (might work too if you get lucky ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you keeping the ObjectContext alive for the entire lifetime of your entities? If not, when you re-attach the entities to a new ObjectContext for saving, the changes made may not be reflected and the entities may not be considered dirty.

Comment: Indeed i did a change that led to this. Not clear why i affects the object context but i commented and it began to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a primary key defined?

Comment: Are you using a generated objectcontext or are you using POCO's

Comment: i use a generated objectcontext